# To express a complex number in polar form

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry, complex-numbers

I came across the following question while studying complex numbers

> Express $\cot(x)+i$ in polar form i.e. in the form $r\{cos(\theta)+i \cdot sin(\theta)\}$.

**My approach is as follows**

Let us assume $z=\cot(x)+i$
Clearly, $\cot(x)$ is a periodic function and $x$ lies in the interval $\big[\frac{-\pi}{2}, 0\big)\cup(0, \frac{\pi}{2}]$. Thus, the following cases arises.

**Case - 1**

When $x \in \big[\frac{-\pi}{2}, 0\big)$.

$|z|= cosec(x)$ ; $\arg(z)=x$.
Thus, $z=cosec(x) \cdot \{\cos(x)+i\cdot \sin(x)\}$.

**Case - 2**

When $x \in \big[0, \frac{\pi}{2}\big)$.

$|z|= cosec(x)$ ; $\arg(z)=\pi +x$.
Thus, $z=cosec(x) \cdot \{\cos(\pi +x)+i\cdot \sin(\pi +x)\}$.

i am not sure if my answer for the second case is correct.
please let me know if my approach is correct and any other  apporach for the aforementioned problem would be highly appreciated.

Thank you

Comment: Is it $x\in\mathbb{C}$? Or $x$ is real?

Comment: x lies in the interval [−π/2,0)∪(0,π/2]

Comment: Should be $|z|=|\csc x|$

Comment: (1) was the restriction to $\left[-\frac \pi 2, 0\right)\cup \left(0, \frac \pi 2\right]$ part of the problem statement you didn't include, or was it your own choice in the solution? (If so, it was wrong.) (2) did you mix up your intervals for case 1 and case 2? Because case 1 is correct for $x \in \left(0,\frac \pi 2\right]$, but incorrect for $\left[-\frac \pi 2, 0\right)$. And for case 2, adding $\pi$ to $x$ makes no sense when $x \in \left(0,\frac \pi 2\right]$.

Comment: Can you please tell that why was the restriction(which is took on my own) was wrong  ??